# Finding the device names and IP addresses connected to the same WiFi network as my Android phone

Tags: c#, android

I want to show the all the device names and local IP address that are connected to the same WiFi network as my Android phone. Is there an API for this or is it possible some other way ?

Comment: Improved grammar and rephrased to be more readable

Answer (score 1):

Goto your router configuration panel

- For D-Link routers, a list of connected devices is available under Status > Wireless.
- On many Netgear routers, you’ll find the list under “Attached Devices” in the sidebar.
- On many Linksys routers, you’ll find this option under Status > Local Network  DHCP Clients Table.
- On Comcast Xfinity routers, you’ll find the list under Connected Devices in the sidebar.

If you have any other router just let me know, I'll try to provide the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response, But My question is i want  to get all the devices under that network like if you turn on your bluetooth you will get all the devices list which are available. like that i want in wifi also..

Comment: Edited the answer, hoping that it'll work for you :)

Comment: Thank you Touseef Rehman, i have one more question, is there any  possibility of getting name of the device with ip address in android programmatically under same network?

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719656/detect-the-cell-phone-connected-to-wireless-network-c-sharp